# logo in print quality

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, print-design, sketch-app

I created a logo using Illustrator. Copy pasted it in Photoshop, saved as PNG.  Opened the PNG file in Sketch and applied a gradient, so created final logo in Sketch.

Now I need to hand the logo to a client in PRINT quality. What do I need to do? Thanks a bunch in advance

Comment: What problem were you trying to solve with this workflow? I mean it must have been quite a problem since your willing to sacrifice so much functionality...

Comment: Do you gradients in AI and send the AI over. AI is print quality and a more commonly used format than Sketch.

Answer (score 1):

Print quality means resolution at least 300dpi. Color mode cmyk is recommended. Vector formats are crisper than rasters.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go back and apply the gradient on Ilustrator with the proper color combination and percentages (Most likely in CMYK format).

The moment you have a PNG to be used on a website (png) you loose totally any "print quality", except for very tiny, and I mean very tiny sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Like Rafael and Webstarian already wrote you need to rework it on illustrator starting with the vector format, some tips to be sure to present a good file to the printer:

- Expand fonts lines and everything that can be expanded just to have all filled shapes.
- Well organize all shapes (trying to clean up overlapping shapes).
- Renane and organize layers with friendly names (avoid duplicates).
- Work with spot colors if the kind of print need it.
- Trying to control gradients.
- Check the black apparence, be sure to have it on Rich Black

Export as pdf version is the most common solution